# If $(\alpha,\beta)$ is a point on $y^2=6x$, that is closest to $(3,\frac{3}{2})$, then find the value 0f $2(\alpha+\beta)$.

Tags: conic-sections

If $(\alpha,\beta)$ is a point on $y^2=6x$, that is closest to $(3,\frac{3}{2})$, then find the value 0f $2(\alpha+\beta)$.

There are many method of doing this problem so I am using the following method and got stuck at the end.

${y^2} = 6x \Rightarrow {y^2} = 4 \times \frac{3}{2} \times x$

$y = mx + \frac{3}{{2m}} \Rightarrow mx - y + \frac{3}{{2m}} = 0$ represent the equation of tangent

Writing in line form we get the followng equation  $\frac{{x - 3}}{m} = \frac{{y - \frac{3}{2}}}{{ - 1}} =  - \frac{{\left( {3m - \frac{3}{2} + \frac{3}{{2m}}} \right)}}{{{m^2} + 1}} \Rightarrow x - 3 =  - \frac{{m\left( {3m - \frac{3}{2} + \frac{3}{{2m}}} \right)}}{{{m^2} + 1}}$

$ \Rightarrow y - \frac{3}{2} = \frac{{\left( {3m - \frac{3}{2} + \frac{3}{{2m}}} \right)}}{{{m^2} + 1}}$

${D^2} = {\left( {x - 3} \right)^2} + {\left( {y - \frac{3}{2}} \right)^2} = \frac{{{{\left( {3m - \frac{3}{2} + \frac{3}{{2m}}} \right)}^2}}}{{{m^2} + 1}}$

$D^2$ needs to be minimum , how do we get the minimum value of $m$.

I have already solved this problem and was experimenting this method to arrive at the answer but not able to proceed

Comment: I don't understand your attempt. If $(h,k)$ is the nearest point on the parabola, then the normal line at $(h,k)$ passes through $(3,3/2)$.

Comment: I am not sure why you would want to complicate the solution when you can simply equate the slopes. But in any case, taking the derivative wrt $m$ and equating to zero should give you the $m$ that minimizes the distance, which btw is $1$.

Comment: If you really want to solve it this way, then you have to find the minimum of your final expression using calculus. No shortcuts. Also you could have simply applied the distance of a point from line formula to the line equation to directly get the final expression

Comment: @DatBol My approach is correct , though I got stuck. If  i Put m=1 I get the required answer